# RLS with USERPRINCIPAL name in separate dataset

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

im trying to implement a RLS but struggling with the logic of it. I want my report rows to be filtered based on who is logged in.

1. Created the security dataset in PBI Desktop, containing UPN, Country and BranchId columns and created a Role called RLS
2. Published this dataset to the PBI service workspace and in Security settings I added AAD group to this role, containing all the users who will be logging in
   Tested this RLS dataset on the service via "test as role" - when entering a UPN of one of those users, only his rows were displayed, everything ok.
3. Then I created a report in PBI Desktop that also contains Country and BranchId columns
4. Via Get Data, I connected to the forementioned RLS dataset via DirectQuery

I guess i need to create a join between the Report dataset and the RLS dataset via BranchId column and then publish it. Tried creating 1:many, but it says this relationship is not valid.

So i created "many to many" and published this Report to the Service, however i cant test it via "test as role" since i didn't create any Role for this Report in Desktop.

My questions are:

- what is the correct relationship between the Report and the RLS dataset so that the Report is filtered based on who is logged in?
- what Role do i need to create in the Report, if any at all?

Here is the diagram:
https://i.ibb.co/Q9TnJSF/pbi-security-ds.png

Any pointers or hints will be very much appreciated.
Many thanks